# Version control and Visual Studio Solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, mercurial

I try to get familiar with version control systems (mercurial to be exact) - nearly everything works as it should, but I have trouble with Solution files of the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 which contain several projects.

Things I add to the ignore list: Bin/debug/Object folders (of course), the .suo file and .csproj files.

Ignoring .csproj files does not seem to be the best idea since other users of my mercurial repository have problems when opening the vs solution: the included projects are "defect".
But including the csproj. files on the other hand also causes trouble as you can read on several pages, or am I wrong here?

What can I do? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring .suo files is a good idea since they contain specific user options. 
Csproj files represent files defining projects in your solution. So solution defines a number of csproj files, and csproj files define what files/folders are contained withing the projects themselves. You absolutely have to add them to the repository.